# Relation between group and normal subgroups isomorphisms with quotient groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ and $H$ are two groups with their respective normal subgroups $K\triangleleft G$, and $L\triangleleft H$. Are there any counterexamples to show that $G \cong H$ and $K \cong L$ dose not imply that $G/K\cong H/L$? How about other combinations: $G \cong H$ and $G/K\cong H/L$ implies $K \cong L$ or 
$G/K\cong H/L$ and $K \cong L$ implies $G \cong H$?

Can anyone point me to a source that has discussed such implications in more detail?

Answer (score 1):

We can find counterexamples just by considering finite abelian groups. If $G$, $N$, $H$ are abelian groups, say $G$ is an [extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext_functor#Ext_and_extensions) of $H$ by $N$ if there is a subgroup of $G$ isomorphic to $N$ with quotient isomorphic to $H$. Then

- $\mathbb Z_8$ is an extension of $\mathbb Z_4$ by $\mathbb Z_2$.
- $\mathbb Z_4\oplus\mathbb Z_2$ is an extension of $\mathbb Z_4$ by $\mathbb Z_2$.
- $\mathbb Z_4\oplus\mathbb Z_2$ is an extension of $\mathbb Z_2\oplus\mathbb Z_2$ by $\mathbb Z_2$.
- $\mathbb Z_4\oplus\mathbb Z_2$ is an extension of $\mathbb Z_2$ by $\mathbb Z_2\oplus\mathbb Z_2$.
- $\mathbb Z_4\oplus\mathbb Z_2$ is an extension of $\mathbb Z_2$ by $\mathbb Z_4$.

This shows that no two of the groups are sufficient to determine the third up to isomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

Let $G=H=\mathbb{Z}/(2)\times\mathbb{Z}/(4)$. Let $K=\langle (1,0)\rangle$ and $L=\langle (0,2)\rangle$.

Then $K\simeq L$ but $G/K\simeq\mathbb{Z}/(4)$ while $G/L\simeq \mathbb{Z}/(2)\times\mathbb{Z}/(2)$.